# Google App Engine MapReduceSpecification exception

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

Rewritten to simplify. Why does this compile:

```
MapReduceSpecification.of(
   "Something, anything", 
   input,
   mapper, // (extends Mapper<Job, Long, String>)
   Marshallers.getLongMarshaller(),
   Marshallers.getStringMarshaller(),
   NoReducer.<Long, String, String>create(),
   NoOutput.<String, String>create((int)1L)
);
```

But this does not. Note the different "mapper" extension in comments:

```
MapReduceSpecification.of(
   "Something, anything", 
   input,
   mapper, // (extends Mapper<Job, Long, JobSummary>)
   Marshallers.getLongMarshaller(),
   Marshallers.getSerializationMarshaller(),
   NoReducer.<Long, JobSummary, JobSummary>create(),
   NoOutput.<JobSummary, JobSummary>create((int)1L)
);
```

Throws this compilation exception:

```
The method
of(String,
Input<I>,
Mapper<I,K,V>,
Marshaller<K>,
Marshaller<V>,
Reducer<K,V,O>, Output<O,R>)
in the type MapReduceSpecification is not applicable for the arguments
(String,
JobInput,
JobMapper,
Marshaller<Long>,
Marshaller<Serializable>,
NoReducer<Long,JobSummary,JobSummary>,
NoOutput<JobSummary,JobSummary>)
```

JobSummary is simple (for purposes of this example):

```
public class JobSummary implements Serializable {
   public String Text;
}
```

Any insight into which bit of the mystery combination of I, K, V, O, R I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating the SerializationMarshaller with a class-specific implementation seems to have solved it. It's a very unsatisfying solution, but it works.